# Email Sending Failed

Tags: email, gmail, phpmailer, cpanel

I am developing a page in that i have to send the email. but i am getting the error in my server mail track and mail is not sending.

ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes: SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550-5.7.1 [188.114.251.250 12] Our system has detected that this message is\n550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail,\n550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit\n550-5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError\n550 5.7.1 for more information. a21si10096467lfk.400 - gsmtp

Please give me solution of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you exactly send that email? Using a php script? You should send it using a SMTP php class and smtp authentication or configure the email headers properly in your php script

Comment: I am using phpmailer package for sending mails.

Comment: You've clearly created a correctly formatted message, and managed to pass gmail's authentication, so it just sounds like gmail doesn't like you or your content. I'd suggest you follow the link they provide and do what it says.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure email headers properly in your script when sending the email message. Like this:

```
<?
$from = "email@domain.com";

$headers = "From: $from
X-Sender: $from
Reply-To: no-reply@domain.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Priority: 5
X-MSMail-Priority: High
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook Express 6.00.2800.1437
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2800.1441
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
";

$subject = "subject";
$message = "whatever";
$to-address = "email address where to send the message";
mail($to-address,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

Please keep in mind that $from address has to be a real address and existing on that server (gmail checks that). Also be sure that you have properly configured SPF, DKIM, DMARC, you have reverse DNS for your server's ip and the server has a valid hostname.

Comment: I'm not even going to begin to list the problems implicit in this script. Just don't do this.